# Webscraping using selenium grid docker cluster

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am working on selenium grid docker to scrape website. If I use only one chrome node means the selenium grid is working if I scale more than one node of chrome selenium grid and the scrapy again it stops  working. It just blinks after some time with big error message.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver

class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "product_spider"
    start_urls = ['https://google.com']

    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

        options.add_argument('--headless')

        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:5000/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)


    def parse(self, response):
        data = self.driver.get(response.url)
        print(data,'/////////////')
```

Then I opened python shell and type the code individual

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
>>> options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
>>> options.add_argument('--headless')
>>> driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:5000/wd/hub',
...             desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

As you see  it stopped in webdriver. Remote .cursor is just blinking for long time then big error message is shown. I think problem is in webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:5000/wd/hub',
...             desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME) line.

Can anyone give a solution for this problem
Note it's working  if selenium grid has one node (chrome) if I scale more than one node (chrome).

This is the error message after long time:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/home/vicky/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 156, in **init**
>       self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)   File "/home/vicky/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 251, in start_session
>       response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)   File "/home/vicky/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 320, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/home/vicky/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Error
>   forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Connect to
>   172.18.0.8:5555 [/172.18.0.8] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) Stacktrace:
>       at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process (RequestHandler.java:117)
>       at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process (DriverServlet.java:84)
>       at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost (DriverServlet.java:68)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:707)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle (ServletHolder.java:860)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle (ServletHandler.java:535)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:188)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle (SessionHandler.java:1595)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:188)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle (ContextHandler.java:1253)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope (ScopedHandler.java:168)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope (ServletHandler.java:473)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope (SessionHandler.java:1564)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope (ScopedHandler.java:166)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope (ContextHandler.java:1155)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:141)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle (Server.java:530)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle (HttpChannel.java:347)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable (HttpConnection.java:256)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded
>   (AbstractConnection.java:279)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable (FillInterest.java:102)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run (ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce
>   (EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce
>   (EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run (EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run
>   (ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:626)

I also attached the selenium grid console screenshot when  multiple node is used.
[link here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWBY1.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're starting up new Selenium nodes with Firefox but your tests specifically look for Chrome.

I'd recommend using Zalenium to set up your Selenium Grid:
https://github.com/zalando/zalenium